# Turtlebot calibration: please point me at a wall

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, turtlebot-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm  ubuntu 12.04,hydro.I want  to calibrate  my  turtlebot1 ,with  the `roslaunch  turtlebot_calibration calibrate.launch`  ,it  launch the 3dsensor.launch.

> it turn out **"Please point me at a wall, Still waiting for scan"**,

```
turtlebot@ubuntu:~$ roslaunch turtlebot_calibration  calibrate.launch
... logging to /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/b4bfc49a-2a99-11e4-a98b-8c705a305c04/roslaunch-ubuntu-11106.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://192.168.0.102:50748/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth/interpolation
 * /camera/depthimage_to_laserscan_loader/output_frame_id
 * /camera/depthimage_to_laserscan_loader/range_min
 * /camera/depthimage_to_laserscan_loader/scan_height
 * /camera/openni_camera_loader/depth_frame_id
 * /camera/openni_camera_loader/depth_mode
 * /camera/openni_camera_loader/depth_registration
 * /camera/openni_camera_loader/depth_time_offset
 * /camera/openni_camera_loader/image_mode
 * /camera/openni_camera_loader/image_time_offset
 * /camera/openni_camera_loader/rgb_frame_id
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /scan_to_angle/max_angle
 * /scan_to_angle/min_angle

NODES
  /camera/
    camera_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    depthimage_to_laserscan_loader (nodelet/nodelet)
    openni_camera_loader (nodelet/nodelet)
    points_xyzrgb (nodelet/nodelet)
  /camera/depth_registered/
    rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
  /
    scan_to_angle (turtlebot_calibration/scan_to_angle.py)
    turtlebot_calibration (turtlebot_calibration/calibrate.py)
  /camera/rgb/
    debayer (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_color (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_mono (nodelet/nodelet)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-1]: started with pid [11124]
process[camera/openni_camera_loader-2]: started with pid [11125]
process[camera/rgb/debayer-3]: started with pid [11140]
process[camera/rgb/rectify_mono-4]: started with pid [11183]
process[camera/rgb/rectify_color-5]: started with pid [11198]
process[camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth-6]: started with pid [11213]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb-7]: started with pid [11236]
process[camera/depthimage_to_laserscan_loader-8]: started with pid [11267]
process[scan_to_angle-9]: started with pid [11297]
process[turtlebot_calibration-10]: started with pid [11301]
[INFO] [WallTime: 1408781227.540423] has_gyro True
[INFO] [WallTime: 1408781227.571398] Estimating imu drift
[INFO] [WallTime: 1408781227.872253] Still waiting for imu
[INFO] [WallTime: 1408781228.173761] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1408781228.475074] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1408781228.776642] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1408781229.077956] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1408781229.378650] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1408781229.679387] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1408781229.980169] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1408781230.280739] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1408781230.581467] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1408781230.882284] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1408781231.183741] Still waiting for scan
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1408781231.248262] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1408781231.278185] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1408781231.309676] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1408781231.341472] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1408781231.377709] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1408781231.406614] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1408781231.439964] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1408781231.477248] Please point me at a wall.
[INFO] [WallTime: 1408781231.484719] Still waiting for scan
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1408781231.516963] Please point me at a wall.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1408781231.557522] Please point me at a wall.
```

just like [link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/39963/please-point-me-at-a-wall-calibration-error/),

when i`run rviz rviz`,i can see  the  **rgb  picture** and **ir  data** ,but **can't see  the depth  data** ,**the  laserscan  data is all "nan"**,

```
header: 
  seq: 20754

  stamp: 
    secs: 1408785070
    nsecs: 317309946

  frame_id: /camera_depth_frame

angle_min: -0.546698212624

angle_max: 0.546698212624

angle_increment: 0.00170843186788

time_increment: 0.0

scan_time: 0.0329999998212

range_min: 0.449999988079

range_max: 10.0

ranges: [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan
```

i have tried many  methods to solve the problems ,but all doesn't  worked.i have no right to upload  my rviz  pictures ,sorry,any suggestions will be appreciated,,thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191095/turtlebot-calibration:-please--point-me-at--a-wall/) by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2014-08-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2014-10-05**:
in  rviz   i can  see the rgb pictures and the  ir  pictures,but when set the image topic is /depth*,,there is nothing ,  does anyone  successfuly  calibrate  your turtlebot1 on hydro ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

thanks [turtlebot-calibration-file-and-access](http://answers.ros.org/question/64416/turtlebot-calibration-file-and-access/) and [turtlebot-calibration-erro](http://answers.ros.org/question/64301/turtlebot-calibration-error/),i solved my problem,just    like

`<include file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/3dsensor.launch"> <arg name="depth_registration" value="false" /> </include>`

---

Originally posted by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) with karma: 252 on 2014-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0